# Выровнялись или выравнялись

Tags: орфография

Все скучились, потом выровнялись (выравнялись) в кое-какой порядок и пошли. Какая буква, и почему?

Answer (score 4):

Здесь выр**а**внялись - не в смысле "ровные" колонны, а в смысле "равные". Так уж повелось спокон веку. Даже команда "равняйсь!" существует.

Дело в том, что строй выравниватся, делается равным, а не ровным.

> Вот как Даль это объясняет.
>
> ВЫРАВНИВАТЬ , | Толковый словарь Даля
>   - выровнять, выравнять что, ровнять, уравнивать, разравнивать. Выровнять > > площадь. Выровнять строй. Выровнять все доли в дележе. В уме
>   концов не выровняешь. -ся, страдат.; становиться ровным, гладким.
>   Дорога ездой выровнялась.
>
> - Становиться равным другим, расти и складываться. Парень вошел в года и 
>     выровнялся.
> - Размещаться по прямой черте. Строй выравнивается по жалонерам.
> - Быть выравниваему, во всех знач. Выравниванье ср. длит. выравнение, 
>     выровнение окончат. действ. по значению глаг.

http://slovari.299.ru/index.php?find_word=%E2%FB%F0%E0%E2%ED%E8%E2%E0%F2%FC&slovar=0

Здесь важна суть процесса, а не орфография, она поменялась с тех пор. 
Смысл же очевидный, хотя и написано через о.

После 1956 г. слова с семантикой "равный" пишутся через а даже без ударения.

Comment: вообще-то строй может и выравняться и выровняться. Без контекста не скажешь. Это если армейский. Но тут-то даже указания на то нету, что про армию. С другой стороны, почему походный порядок ровный? Почему "равный" - я могу понять. одинаковый. Похоже, вы правы.

Answer (score 3):

**Все скучились, потом выровнялись в кое-какой порядок и пошли.**

Выровнялись ― встали ровно, образовали группу с ровными рядами.

Корень РОВН имеет значение "ровный, плавный", а корень РАВН ― равный, одинаковый.

**Можно сравнить команды:**

**Равняйсь!** (По правофланговому, встать одинаково с ним). **Выровнять ряды!** (Обеспечить ровную линию ряда).

Comment: Перед входом в колонию снова построились, **выравнялись** и снова запели песню, хотя она уже с большим трудом могла осилить нараставший шум ливня и неожиданно приятные, как салют нашему возвращению, первые в этом году раскаты грома. [А. С. Макаренко. Педагогическая поэма. Часть 2 (1934)]

Comment: Все наездники **выровнялись** перед палаткой в одну линию, и бий подал знак. [Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Ак-Бозат (1895)]

Comment: Когда мы **выровнялись**, была подана через мегафон команда «вперед!» [Александр Крон. Капитан дальнего плавания (1983)

Comment: Ждали командира дивизии, и все подтянулись, лихо заломили фуражки набекрень и даже **выравнялись**, совсем как на плацу. [Н. С. Гумилев. Записки кавалериста]

Comment: Похоже, оба варианта употребимы...

Comment: Возможно,  в старых текстах  (до 1956 года) использовались оба варианта. В современной орфографии они, я думаю, различаются.  В словах с корнем РАВН присутствую предметы, которые сравниваются, равный - это одинаковый.  Поэтому различаются слова "равняться" (на кого-то)  и выровняться, подровняться, встать ровно.

Comment: Я думаю, дело не во времени (в старой орфографии, даже до 1956 г. никто издавать не будет), а в разнице значений. То что касается строя - выравнялись, все остальное - выровнялись. В отношении цитаты из Крона - не мог сказать априори, посмотрел. Там речь идет о яхте. ***"Равнение на середину!"*** - ну что тут может быть "ровного"? Только "равный", одинаковый. Как все.

Comment: ВЫРОВНЯТЬСЯ,  св. 1. только 3 л. Стать ровным, плоским, гладким. Лёд на катке выровнялся. 2. только 3 л. Расположиться, направиться по прямой линии в вертикальной или горизонтальной плоскости. Выйдя из пике, самолёты выровнялись в нескольких метрах от земли. // Стать прямым; расположиться по прямой. Фронт выровнялся. Шеренга выровнялась.